# How to set ATmega88PA fuses in code or HEX file

Tags: avr, atmel

I'm a Microchip guy, but I'm helping a customer out with an Atmel project using the ATmega88PA project they inherited from another division. I'm using AVR Studio 5 and I would like to compile the fuse selections into the source code and eventually hex file. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, they have to be set in AVR Studio.

If you use the AVRdude utility, programming and fuse settings can be automated with makefiles.

Comment: So, how do you setup production for these chips? Is there another fuse setup file I have to generate?

Comment: Either save the fuse options as command line values or in a file as is described here: http://electrons.psychogenic.com/modules/arms/art/14/AVRFusesHOWTOGuide.php and also fuse calculator here: http://www.engbedded.com/fusecalc/

Comment: @kenny That is a good question (maybe you should ask it). We use a command line programmer and call it with the correct fuse bit settings from scripts (each product gets a new script) but we are a rather small shop. What do the big guys use for AVRs?

Comment: @AngryEE and @jpc, thanks. I didn't realize those command line tools existed. And I see that AVRDude is a console application now.

Comment: jpc: I would think that large companies use a gang programmer that can load the fuse configuration from a file, or get their chips supplied pre-programmed.

Comment: Gang programmer, ha!  He'll set a fuse in yo chip.